# pyuic5.exe doesnt output anything and clears the input file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, designer

This is a small test that im trying to convert to python code via pyuic5:

https://pastebin.com/rBDKhvCV

When using the pyuic5.exe from the Scripts folder in my Venv like this:

```
(Test) C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Test\Repo>..\Scripts\pyuic5.exe -o Test.ui QtOutput.py
```

I get this output:

```
Error in input file: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Afterwards, QtOutput.py is still empty, but Test.ui no longer contains the "designer code", but instead only this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'QtOutput.py'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
```

What is this? Why isnt it working? Im doing everything exactly like the online documentation says, i think? (using what the people at https://python-forum.io/Thread-Convert-ui-file-py said)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct use of pyuic is:

```
pyuic5 -o target_py_file.py my_ui_file.ui
```

You're currently telling to pyuic to process the QtOutput.py file and to write the output in the Test.ui file.

> The `-o` option stands for 'output'

Comment: Oh damn, on the source i linked some guy said that you need it the other way around, and noone pointed out that this was wrong, so i took it as true:
```C:\Python36\Scripts\pyuic5.exe -o FirstApp.ui FirstApp.py``` , thanks for clarifying!